# backbone make jquery and underscore available everywhere without calling them

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I define thing like this:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: [
                'underscore',
                'jquery'
            ],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },      
    },

    paths: {
        jquery: 'libs/external/jquery',
        underscore:'libs/external/underscore',
        backbone: 'libs/external/backbone',
        text: 'libs/external/text',
        router: ''
    }
});
```

Then in my views I have to require jquery and underscore everytime which is annoying:

```
define('myview',[
    'jquery',
    'backbone',
    'underscore',
    'somemodule'
    ], function($, backbone, underscore) {
```

I know there is a method to define some library gloablly, that can be called accross views/model/collections...etc without requiring them all the time but I can't remember the proper implementation.

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: Note that this would pretty much defeat the purpose of using RequireJS - you'll be unable to track each modules' dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

They are already available to be used without defining them.

1. jQuery already exports itself as a global variable

   From http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html

   > jQuery registers itself as the global variables "`$`" and "`jQuery`", even when it detects AMD/RequireJS. The AMD approach advises against the use of global functions, but the decision to turn off these jQuery globals hinges on whether you have non-AMD code that depends on them. jQuery has a noConflict function that supports releasing control of the global variables and this can be automated in your requirejs.config

   So unless you go with defining `noConflict` you can access `$` and `jQuery` as they are attached to `window` object
2. Backbone and Underscore are also available as global variables since they are being exported in the shim config.
   See http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim and [RequireJS - What is the purpose of the "exports" property in shim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095308/requirejs-what-is-the-purpose-of-the-exports-property-in-shim)

So, the following code should work

```
define(['myview'], function(MyView) {
    console.log($); // window.$
    console.log(Backbone); // window.Backbone
    console.log(_); // window._
}
```

Comment: hmm thank you i'm gonna test it. But why in the todomvc example they alway require backbone,jquery ... ? https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/backbone_require/js/views/app.js

Comment: probably for the reason kryger mentioned in the comments to your question that is to track module dependencies